# Copying to the clipboard in Java

Tags: java, string, clipboard, awt

I want to set the user's clipboard to a string in a Java console application. Any ideas?

Comment: I tried using AWT to no avail.

Comment: then show what you've tried and tell us what exactly didn't work

Answer (score 152):

Use the [`Toolkit`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Toolkit.html) to get the [system clipboard](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Toolkit.html#getSystemClipboard). Create a [`StringSelection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/datatransfer/StringSelection.html) with the `String` and add it to the `Clipboard`.

Simplified:

```
StringSelection selection = new StringSelection(theString);
Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
clipboard.setContents(selection, selection);
```

Comment: It didn't work for me, the clipboard was cleared. I'm using Linux.

Comment: it should, maybe consider the second comment on original question, or rado's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11059985/85421) below

Answer (score 38):

Here is a simple [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) to accomplish this:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.datatransfer.*;
import java.io.*;

class ClipboardTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
        throws UnsupportedFlavorException, IOException
    {
        Clipboard c = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
        StringSelection testData;

        //  Add some test data

        if (args.length > 0)
            testData = new StringSelection( args[0] );
        else
            testData = new StringSelection( "Test Data" );

        c.setContents(testData, testData);

        //  Get clipboard contents, as a String

        Transferable t = c.getContents( null );

        if ( t.isDataFlavorSupported(DataFlavor.stringFlavor) )
        {
            Object o = t.getTransferData( DataFlavor.stringFlavor );
            String data = (String)t.getTransferData( DataFlavor.stringFlavor );
            System.out.println( "Clipboard contents: " + data );
        }

        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 14):

For anyone still stumbling upon this post searching for the [JavaFX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaFX) way to accomplish this, here you go:

```
ClipboardContent content = new ClipboardContent();
content.putString("Some text");
content.putHtml("<b>Bold</b> text");
Clipboard.getSystemClipboard().setContent(content);
```

For further information, [read the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/input/Clipboard.html).

Answer (score 2):

If you are on Linux and using OpenJDK, it will not work. You must use the Sun JDK on Linux for it to work.

Comment: Why? do you have more information about it? A bug report? You could get some reputation ;) http://stackoverflow.com/q/14242719/194609

Comment: What will not work? Is this a response to one of the other answers?

Comment: This is very wrong. Sun JDK isd openjdk build as everything else, and clipoabrd on linux, including java as client, works fine

Answer (score 1):

In Linux with xclip:

```
Runtime run = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process p = null;
String str = "hello";
try {
        p = run.exec(new String[]{"sh", "-c", "echo " + str + " | xclip -selection clipboard"});
}
catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

Comment: What if the string contains end-of-line characters? Will it work then?

Comment: that really defeats the idea of a multi platform programming language..

Comment: This is lacking any kind of sanitation. Please don't use this in production code. If someone copies the string `" rm -rf $HOME`, you've just deleted  their home directory. Also, I believe Ubuntu doesn't come with xclip by default.

Comment: @Sean You're right. That's why I came up with the following solution:
`String text = "text_to_copy_to_clipboard"; ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("xclip", "-selection", "clipboard"); BufferedWriter bw = null; try { Process process = pb.start(); bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(process.getOutputStream())); bw.write(text); } finally {if (bw != null) bw.close();}`