# Copying text to the clipboard using Java

Tags: java, swing, text, clipboard

I want to copy text from a `JTable`'s cell to the clipboard, making it available to be pasted into other programs such as Microsoft Word. I have the text from the `JTable`, but I am unsure how to copy it to the clipboard.

Answer (score 350, accepted):

This works for me and is quite simple:

Import these:

```
import java.awt.datatransfer.StringSelection;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.datatransfer.Clipboard;
```

And then put this snippet of code wherever you'd like to alter the clipboard:

```
String myString = "This text will be copied into clipboard";
StringSelection stringSelection = new StringSelection(myString);
Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
clipboard.setContents(stringSelection, null);
```

Comment: we can setContents() with owner too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3591945/copying-to-clipboard-in-java

Comment: @AquariusPower It seems that passing `stringSelection` as the 2nd argument to `setContents(..)` too, making it the `ClipboardOwner`, as in the linked answer, has no significance: looking at the [source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/awt/datatransfer/StringSelection.java#StringSelection.lostOwnership%28java.awt.datatransfer.Clipboard%2Cjava.awt.datatransfer.Transferable%29), the sole method of `ClipboardOwner` that it implements, namely, `lostOwnership(..)`, is empty. So, the 2nd argument seems to be a completely optional callback.

Comment: @EvgeniSergeev it may be useful if we extend StringSelection :)

Comment: Ported to Clojure: `(-> (java.awt.Toolkit/getDefaultToolkit) .getSystemClipboard (.setContents (java.awt.datatransfer.StringSelection. "test") nil))`

Comment: In which context did you test this? From a GUI application? On which platform? Does it work setting the clipboard 100 times in a row (with some appropriate pause between each set)?

Answer (score 34):

This is the accepted answer written in a decorative way:

```
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit()
        .getSystemClipboard()
        .setContents(
                new StringSelection(txtMySQLScript.getText()),
                null
        );
```

Answer (score 21):

The following class allows you to copy/paste a String to/from the clipboard.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.datatransfer.Clipboard;
import java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor;
import java.awt.datatransfer.StringSelection;

import static java.awt.event.KeyEvent.*;
import static org.apache.commons.lang3.SystemUtils.IS_OS_MAC;

public class SystemClipboard
{
    public static void copy(String text)
    {
        Clipboard clipboard = getSystemClipboard();
        clipboard.setContents(new StringSelection(text), null);
    }

    public static void paste() throws AWTException
    {
        Robot robot = new Robot();

        int controlKey = IS_OS_MAC ? VK_META : VK_CONTROL;
        robot.keyPress(controlKey);
        robot.keyPress(VK_V);
        robot.keyRelease(controlKey);
        robot.keyRelease(VK_V);
    }

    public static String get() throws Exception
    {
        Clipboard systemClipboard = getSystemClipboard();
        DataFlavor dataFlavor = DataFlavor.stringFlavor;

        if (systemClipboard.isDataFlavorAvailable(dataFlavor))
        {
            Object text = systemClipboard.getData(dataFlavor);
            return (String) text;
        }

        return null;
    }

    private static Clipboard getSystemClipboard()
    {
        Toolkit defaultToolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
        return defaultToolkit.getSystemClipboard();
    }
}
```

Comment: May need some logic for pasting in OS X since it's special.

Comment: @BenLeggiero: Late answer but feel free to suggest an edit to support `OS X` better in case it's not working properly

Comment: if I ever need to do this again, I'll update. Likely, it's just checking the current OS, and swapping out `VK_CONTROL` for `VK_META` if it's macOS.

Comment: This is what I need it.

Answer (score 9):

For **JavaFx** based applications.

```java
        //returns System Clipboard
        final Clipboard clipboard = Clipboard.getSystemClipboard();
        // ClipboardContent provides flexibility to store data in different formats
        final ClipboardContent content = new ClipboardContent();
        content.putString("Some text");
        content.putHtml("<b>Some</b> text");
        //this will be replaced by previous putString
        content.putString("Some different text");
        //set the content to clipboard
        clipboard.setContent(content);
       // validate before retrieving it
        if(clipboard.hasContent(DataFormat.HTML)){
            System.out.println(clipboard.getHtml());
        }
        if(clipboard.hasString()){
            System.out.println(clipboard.getString());
        }
```

**ClipboardContent** can save multiple data in several data formats like(html,url,plain text,image).

For more information see [official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/input/ClipboardContent.html)

Answer (score 4):

For reference:

```
static void copyToClipboard(String text) {
    java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard()
        .setContents(new java.awt.datatransfer.StringSelection(text), null);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I found a better way of doing it so you can get a input from a txtbox or have something be generated in that text box and be able to click a button to do it.!

```
import java.awt.datatransfer.*;
import java.awt.Toolkit;

private void /* Action performed when the copy to clipboard button is clicked */ {
    String ctc = txtCommand.getText().toString();
    StringSelection stringSelection = new StringSelection(ctc);
    Clipboard clpbrd = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
    clpbrd.setContents(stringSelection, null);
}

// txtCommand is the variable of a text box
```

Comment: What do you mean by "2017/2018"? A particular version of Java? Which version *did* you use?

Answer (score -2):

For reference here are the `copy` and `paste` functions from/to the system clipboard written in [Clojure](https://clojure.org) (so related to Java):

```clj
(defn copy [s]
  (-> (java.awt.Toolkit/getDefaultToolkit)
      .getSystemClipboard
      (.setContents (java.awt.datatransfer.StringSelection. s) nil)))

(defn paste []
  (-> (java.awt.Toolkit/getDefaultToolkit)
      .getSystemClipboard
      (.getContents nil)
      (.getTransferData java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor/stringFlavor)))

(copy "Hello!")
(paste) ;=> "Hello!"
```