# testing JTextField.paste()

Tags: java, swing, junit, jtextfield

I want to test JTextField.paste(), however it is not working.

I created a JUnit test with the following code:

```
JTextField textfield = new JTextField();
textfield.paste();
assertEquals("my text", textfield.getText())
```

however, textfield.getText() is empty (I copied "my text" to the clipboard, before)

Can you help me?

Comment: yeah, sure - where else if you are asking about a unit test ;-) Check if there's really something on the clipboard, f.i. along the lines of @Grove's answer

Comment: Cool, it is working. I am not sure what I did wrong, however it works now :-)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could try forcing the "copy-to-clipboard" operation before pasting the text, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6710350/copying-text-to-the-clipboard-using-java)