# How to fix java.awt.HeadlessException in Jenkins on Linux

Tags: java, linux, jenkins, awt

I use [some AWT code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6710350/copying-text-to-the-clipboard-using-java#answer-6713290) in my Java app which ran fine until I unit tested it on Linux Mint Debian Edition via Jenkins and Gradle:
I now get that nasty `java.awt.HeadlessException` which is explained [here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/738b7897-cd38-4f24-9f05-48dd69116837/entry/how_to_resolve_java_exceptions_java_awt_headlessexception7?lang=en).

The unsuccessful unit test causes my build to fail; how do I fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are the steps that rid me of the HeadlessException:

1. Add the [Xvnc plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Xvnc+Plugin) to Jenkins
2. Install [VNC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Network_Computing): `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install
   vnc4server`
3. Make sure Jenkins has a shell: `sudo usermod -s /bin/bash jenkins`
4. Log in as Jenkins: `sudo su jenkins`
5. Enter the command `vnc4server` and choose a password
6. Tick `Run Xvnc during build` in Jenkins' build config

Comment: What is the password for? It is not necessary to store it in Jenkins.

Comment: @kap: `vnc4server` demands a password the first time it's started. This password is not stored in Jenkins though but rather in `~/.vncpasswd` if I'm not mistaken.