# Java Headless exception when trying to run an executable jar in Jenkins after the build process

Tags: java, macos, maven, jenkins, operating-system

I am trying to run a jar file that was build using Maven (It an executable jar file) in Jenkins. The project has some swing elements in it. The jar executes correctly in my terminal but not through Jenkins server. After maven build, i had configured Jenkins to execute the following script.

```
java -jar target/myProject.jar
```

I got the following error at Jenkins console

```
  FD1] $ /bin/sh -xe /Users/Shared/Jenkins/tmp/hudson4108598998187356561.sh
  + java -jar target/myProject.jar 
  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
  at  com.myProject.main(mainEx.java:26)
 Caused by: java.awt.HeadlessException: 
 No X11 DISPLAY variable was set, but this program performed an 
 operation which requires it.
```

I was sitting for hours for a work around for this situation. It has to do something with display. I would really appreciate if someone can help me out here. I am using a mac system

Comment: what is your operating system is it headless ?

Comment: It is mac OSX 10.9.3. Not a linux system. I am running the jar in a local jenkins server i created in my machine. It runs in a browser

Comment: which version exactly ?

Comment: jar doesn't run in browser (unless its an applet)

Comment: I am not trying to make it run in a browser. I just want that jar to execute after Jenkins has completed the build process with Maven. My OS is mac OSX 10.9.3

Comment: and jenkins server is running on your local mac oS ?

Comment: Yes. i created my own local server

Comment: what is your `java -version`

Comment: please post full output

Comment: I meant full output of `java -version`

Comment: java version "1.7.0_60"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_60-b19)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.60-b09, mixed mode)

Comment: @JigarJoshi Is there somehow i can do 'ssh -X hostname' in the script before running the jar.  Since i am running a local server what will be the hostname?

Comment: are you ssh (ing) to local host ?

Comment: i can try to do it. So what should i put in hostname? My jenkins server is localhost:8080

Comment: you shouldn;t ssh just goto directory where jenkins generates this jar and try running manually from terminal

Comment: the jar executes perfectly through my terminal but i can't make it work through my jenkins server @JigarJoshi

Comment: how did you configure jenkins task to launch this jar ? can you post snapshot

Comment: So I have configured POM such that Maven creates an executable jar after the build process in Jenkins. Now the executable jar is in the target folder. Now i just need to run the following script java -jar target/myProject.jar in the 'Execute Shell' of 'Build' of Jenkins. Hope you understood @JigarJoshi

Comment: very well :)  try to `echo $DISPLAY` in your execute shell section before this java command, and post its value

Comment: [FD1] $ /bin/sh -xe /Users/Shared/Jenkins/tmp/hudson6693357725188547209.sh
+ echo

Finished: SUCCESS

Comment: I dint execute the jar here...i just echoed the value of display. It just gave some blank space. The echo $DISPLAY gives blank space in my terminal also

Comment: I was just make it working fine on my local jenkins instance on mac, I still doubt, what does it output when you ask jenkins to `hostname` and `whoami` inside execute shell

Comment: @JigarJoshi I am not sure this would be helpful. But i would try this   https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Xvnc+Plugin

Comment: I just wanted to confirm the hostname and user, I see no other issue, I just ran it fine on my jenkins on mac

Comment: @JigarJoshi the issue is my project uses GUI elements like Swing.. maybe your build doesn't need a gui element that why it works

Comment: I tested with a simple `JFrame`

Comment: the whoami gives jenkins and hostname gives the same hostname as the terminal output @JigarJoshi

Comment: looks like there is another user `jenkins` which jenkins installation has created and which doesn't have GUI environment, I am running jenkins under tomcat, if that is not hard for you I would ask you to uninstall jenkins and download apache tomcat and deploy jenkins as war and use it under same user as you (btw your comment with CAPS letter doesn't look good :))

Comment: i got it... i think you are right about this

Comment: Cool ! It was tricky <!---->

Comment: @JigarJoshi I am right now using Jenkins deployed in a remote server. It is an headless system and i am wondering is there anyway to get around the headless exception now?  There is an article about Xvnc pluggin. Will this be a solution? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21778124/how-to-fix-java-awt-headlessexception-in-jenkins-on-linux

Comment: no idea about that plugin

Comment: @JigarJoshi what should i do to execute this jar as a windows batch command instead of execute shell ? What will be a script for running that batch command. Since windows is not a headless system, this approach might work. Can u help me out?

Comment: it is the same command `java -jar yourJar.jar`

Comment: @JigarJoshi That dint workout. It gave me this error      "cmd /c call /tmp/hudson2033384960131825453.bat
FATAL: command execution failed
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "cmd" (in directory "/hosting/workspace/myProject"): error=2, No such file or directory"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out that jenkins service was running under user `jenkins` which had headless account and so the error

solution is to switch jenkins installation to user which has GUI access (Simple way is to deploy jenkins under tomcat container)

Comment: This solution is perfect