# Java Headless Exception while building through Jenkins of a remote server

Tags: java, jenkins

I am facing a big issue while building a project through jenkins which is in a remote server. Now this being a headless system i get a  headless exception. I came across this post in stack overflow to use the Xvnc pluggin. [How to fix java.awt.HeadlessException in Jenkins on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21778124/how-to-fix-java-awt-headlessexception-in-jenkins-on-linux)
Now the jenkins which i use in the server, has already this pluggin (Since this is hosted by my company). Under the build Environment of Jenkins i have this option  "Run Xvnc during build". I check this and start building my project i get the error as

$ vncserver :39 -localhost -nolisten tcp

You will require a password to access your desktops.

In the stack overflow solution posted before, it says to install VNC and all those stuff. Where should i install VNC? I dont have access to the server since that is secured environment. i can't understand steps 3 to 6. Should i run a bash script with the build process for that? I am new to jenkins and i am having trouble following that post