# [JAVA]Paste a String to the current position of my curser where clicked in by tiping a key on my Keyboard

Tags: java, string, keyboard, paste

Searching for a solution a while now, but don't find one.
I would like to build a tool that allows me to paste texts into a text field if I press a key on my keyboard.
E.g. when I'm writing emails.

Is that even possible in Java?

Thanks for helping!

Comment: You can use Clipboard system of Java. Take a look of these documentation s http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=82 or https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/datatransfer/Clipboard.html

Comment: See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6710350/8685250

Comment: @SebaLópez The Clipboard system you linked does not provide functionality to paste, which is what the question is asking about. It allows you to put text into the clipboard or read the contents of the clipboard, but not paste.