# Can you create a file on the system clipboard but not in a directory?

Tags: java, file, clipboard

When a user clicks a button I would like to generate and add the file to the system clipboard. I have been able to do this, but when the file is added to the system clipboard, it also generates the file in the project folder (I'm using Eclipse). Can I make it directly on the system clipboard and not have it show up in a directory?

When I make a file, here is the code I use:

```
File file = new File("file.txt");
```

should `"file.txt"` be replaced with a path to the system clipboard? Or is that not possible?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3591945/copying-to-clipboard-in-java

Comment: What would I put for the selection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not create a file in the path of your project. You know that when you create file using the following statement:

```
File file = new File("file.txt");
```

It is being created near the class file of your code.

Just create a temp file using the `createTempFile` static method of class `File` :

```
try {
        File f = File.createTempFile("file", ".txt");
        FileWriter wr = new FileWriter(f);
        wr.write("This is a Test!");
        wr.close();
        // Add it to clipboard here 
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Good Luck

Comment: I probably should have explained, I use a method to generate a file, and the method returns that file. If I use this approach will the return type generate a file?

Comment: Yes it is a file. As you can see I stored it in a `File` variable. The only difference is it is temp file, and when your program ends, it will not be there.

Comment: By the way, the second parameter should be ".txt" - without the dot, the file name is "file123456txt".

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou: Thanks for the tip. Edited.

Comment: Also, this creates a file in the TEMP directory - so it's still going to be on the disk.

Answer (score 2):

```
        StringSelection sel = new StringSelection(<insert string here>);
        Clipboard clip = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
        clip.setContents(sel, sel);
```

You can view this for string selection http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/datatransfer/StringSelection.html