# Copy StringBuffer to Clipboard

Tags: java

Since it is possible to copy a `String` to the `Clipboard`, is it also possible to copy a `StringBuffer` to it? The advantage would be increased capability of saving data or has the Clipboard limitations?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3591945/copying-to-clipboard-in-java) is a similiar approach but a `String` has been used in this example, which size can't be bigger than `2147483647`. But I was thinking of copying more than that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Copying to Clipboard in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3591945/copying-to-clipboard-in-java)

Comment: @CaptainMagikarp this is not a duplicate because I am not using `JavaScript` but `Java` and the second link is refering to a solution using a `String` but I wanted to know whether it's possible to do it with a `StringBuffer`

Comment: You can actually copy to the clipboard whatever you like. If you want some special object in there you'll need to create a custom `java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor` for it. You can use this in your application, but other applications won't know how to handle non-standard clipboard contents.

Comment: @dpr can you provide an example, because it seems like you can only use `DataFlavor` when retreiving information from `Clipboard`.

Comment: You will need to use `Clipboard.setContents(Transferable contents, ClipboardOwner owner)` and implement `Transferable`. This wraps your `DataFlavor`.

Comment: You shouldn't be using `StringBuffer`, by the way. There's really no use case for it. Use `StringBuilder`. Why not put the `toString` value in the clipboard; it'll be easier and simpler.