# Changin syscalls global (temporarily?)

Tags: java, windows, operating-system, hook, shellexecute

I have installed a software (java application - not my own, No sourcecode available!) which opens the browser (specific link) after pressing a button. Is it possible to change that behaviour to just "copy the link to clipboard"?

Maybe a global sys call modification? The problem: i dont know anything about hooks, syscalls etc. but i know that the program is opening the process "run32dll.exe" and uses the api "shellexecuteA(URL)"

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Copying to Clipboard in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3591945/copying-to-clipboard-in-java)

Comment: Edited post - it is not my own software

Comment: You can use a Java decompiler to get the source code, modify it and use Java compiler to turn it back into the application. Or you can register your own application as a default browser, your application would receive the specific link as the command line argument

Comment: Thanks xmojmr, that is a good idea